# When is is true that $\frac{X_n}{n}\rightarrow -N\implies \sup_\limits{n\ge0}X_n<\infty$?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, supremum-and-infimum

> When $\frac{X_n}{n}$ converges almost surely to a negative value, then does it follow that $\sup_\limits{n\ge0}X_n<\infty$ almost surely ?

Are there any further constraints needed to ensure that ?

EDIT: For example $X_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} Y_k$ where $Y_k$ are iid r.v. with distribution

$P(Y_k=1)=p<\frac12$ and $P(Y_k=-1)=1-p>\frac12$

Comment: The $X_n$ in your edit have $X_n/n \to 0$ almost surely, not to a negative value.

Comment: @RhysSteele If $p$ is chosen in such a way, $P(Y_k=1)=p<1/2$ and $P(Y_k=-1)=1-p>1/2$ then $\frac{X_n}{n}\rightarrow E(Y_1)=2p-1<0$ am I wrong ?

Comment: No, that's fine. I assumed you meant Bernoulli$(1/2)$ rather than Bernoulli$(p)$ for $p < 1/2$. Still, you need to fix the range of $p$. In this case, the argument given in the answer below does just work though. All that answer needs is $X_n < \infty$ almost surely.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be the negative a.s. limit of $\frac{X_n}{n}$ and $A=\{\omega:\frac{X_n(\omega)}{n}\to a\}$. Then $P(A)=1$.

If there is $\omega\in A$ such that $\sup_{n\geq0}X_n(\omega)=\infty$, then there is a subsequence $X_{n_k}(\omega)$ such that $X_{n_k}(\omega)\geq 0$ for all $k$ and thus 
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{X_{n_k}(\omega)}{n_k}\geq 0$$
and so 
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{X_{n}(\omega)}{n}\geq 0,$$
contradicting to the choice of $\omega$ since $a<0$.
Hence
$$\{\omega:\frac{X_n(\omega)}{n}\to a\}\subset \{\omega:\sup_{n\geq0} X_n(\omega)<\infty\},$$
and desired result follows.

Comment: Sorry but what if $X_n$ is piecewise defined, for example it is constant but for a specific $N$, we have $X_N=\infty$ ?

Comment: @counterfeit This answer works if you assume that each $X_n$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}$ which I think was assumed you intended since if you allow $X_n$ to take the value $\infty$ then it is clear that the result is false by setting $X_1 = \infty$ and then $X_n = -n$ for $n \geq 2$

Comment: @RhysSteele Yeah thats what I was asking, when $X_n=\sum_{k=1}^n Y_k$ where $Y_k$ are iid and can take only values $1$ or $-1$